# How to load image + code into dropdown from database Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I want to populate stored images from database to fill dropdown the images are in airline_images folder the image path is stored in database i want user when click on the airlines dropdown it will show the stored airliens with its images

here is the blade code :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
   <label>@lang('site.airline')</label>
   <select class="form-control select2 status-type" style="width: 100%;"
      name="airline"
      id="airline">
      @foreach ($airlines as $airline)
      <option value="{{ $airline->code }}">{{ $airline->name }} <img src="{{ $airline->image_path }}" style="width: 100px" class="img-thumbnail" alt="">
      </option>
      @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using 3rd party jQuery library like [ddSlick](https://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo)

**Usage**

```
$('select#airline').ddslick({
    data: ddData,
    width: '100%',
    imagePosition: "left",
    selectText: "Select your favorite airline",
    onSelected: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

PS : The plugin requires specific data format

```
var ddData = [
    {
        text: "Tunisair",
        value: 1,
        selected: false,
        description: "Description goes here",
        imageSrc: "http://path_to_img"
    },
    {
        text: "Turkish airlines",
        value: 2,
        selected: true,
        description: "Description goes here",
        imageSrc: "http://path_to_img"
    },
    {
        text: "Lufthansa",
        value: 3,
        selected: false,
        description: "Description goes here",
        imageSrc: "http://path_to_img"
    },
    //...
];
```

Comment: the airlines are stored in another table thay are not static options as you can see iam using foreach loop